# Why the need to say "à cause d'infos" instead of "à cause des infos"?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles

> Je veux juste éviter que quelqu'un d'autre soit blessé **à cause d'infos** auxquelles je n'aurais pas eues accès.

Considering that the noun "infos" is qualified by the phrase "auxquelles je n'aurais pas eues accès", isn’t it more appropriate to say "à cause des infos" {"à cause de **les** infos"}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"à cause de"/because of* is a locution preposition. It means this is a row  of words you have to learn as its global form.

*"à cause des informations"/because of the informations* : here you have to understand "de + s" and not "des", this is a contraction of *"de + les"* and also refer to the indefinite article *"les"* : you know what are these informations.

*"à cause d'informations"/because of informations :* refer to the indefinite article *"des"* : you don't know anything about these informations. We  talk about informations in general.

I know, french exceptions could be tricky...
Hope it helped